# SQL Query to select products from all categories of a parent

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a categories table like this

Table - categories

```
cat_id     cat_name         parent_id
---------------------------------------
21         Properties            0
--------------------------------------
32         For Rent             21
---------------------------------------
34        Appartments           32
---------------------------------------
35        Houses and villas     32
--------------------------------------
36        Builder Floors        32
-----------------------------------------
```

Product table like this

Table - products

```
ProductID            ProductName         CategoryID
------------------------------------------------------
39                     villa                 35
-----------------------------------------------------
40                     Flat                  35
----------------------------------------------------
41                     appartment            34
------------------------------------------------------
42                     Builder               36
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to fetch all the products exists in the parrent category Properties(21).. also this same query needs to work in case of single category like, in case of `cateogryID = 35`  i need the products exists in the `CategoryID 35` only..

Currently iam using the query is:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductTitle,p.SalePrice,p.C_Date,p.ProductShortDescription, c.cat_name, 
c.cat_id
from products p JOIN
(select * from categories where cat_id =32 OR parent_id = 32 ) c
on p.CategoryID = c.cat_id
```

This query works fine for me... but in case of parrent category Properties(21) its not working.. On all other cases its works fine.

Please help me to alter the above query.. for Properties(21)

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I need to fetch all the products under the category properties(21). products from cat - 32,34,35,36

Comment: you should use php for that because the amount of `left joins` rise dramatically in relation of the amount of your parent categories ....

Comment: its not clear.. can you give me a example

Answer (score 0):

you can use **LEFT JOIN**

```
   SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductTitle,
    p.SalePrice,
    p.C_Date,
    p.ProductShortDescription,
    c.cat_name,
    c.cat_id
FROM
    products p
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        categories
    WHERE
        cat_id = 32 OR parent_id = 32) c ON p.CategoryID = c.cat_id
```

**Update**

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductTitle,
    p.SalePrice,
    p.C_Date,
    p.ProductShortDescription,
    c.cat_name,
    c.cat_id
FROM
    products p
        LEFT JOIN
    categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.cat_id
WHERE
    c.cat_id = 21 OR c.parent_id = 21
```

Comment: I Updated the Query

Comment: hi.. this query fetching the whole records from my products table , i think its because of the LEFT JOIN.. If i given cat_id 36 there is only one record in the product table.. but here the whole products data is taking..

Comment: All others are working fine except parent category. eg- 21
For 21 in need the whole products exists under the category "properties"

Comment: can you post your mail id here.. then i can send my sql file.

Comment: Mail send to you... Thanks!